# Why multiple clone system calls called for single go subroutine?

Tags: linux, go, linux-kernel, pthreads, subroutine

I created small sample program to check sub-routine system call.

```
package main

func print() {
}

func main() {
    go print()
}
```

**Straces of go subroutine**

```
clone(child_stack=0xc000044000, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM) = 27010
clone(child_stack=0xc000046000, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM) = 27011
clone(child_stack=0xc000040000, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM) = 27012
futex(0x4c24a8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
futex(0xc000034848, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

It is observed that three times clone system call called for single subroutine but stack size is small as go is claiming. Can you please let me know why three clone system call called for single subroutine.

In the similar manner when creating a pthread single time clone system call called. but stack size is big.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> //Header file for sleep(). man 3 sleep for details.
#include <pthread.h>

void *myThreadFun(void *vargp)
{
        return NULL;
}

int main()
{
        pthread_t thread_id;
        pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, myThreadFun, NULL);
        pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
        exit(0);
}
```

**Straces of pthread**

```
clone(child_stack=0x7fb49d960ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARET_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fb49d9619d0, tls=0x7fb49d961700, child_tidptr=0x7fb49d9619d0) = 27370
futex(0x7fb49d9619d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 27370, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
exit_group(0) = ?
```

Why multiple clone system calls called for single go subroutine? because in the program only single sub-routine was created like single pthread in second program of C language. For what purpose other two clone called?

Comment: You are observing Go program initialization. Go manages its own stacks. Micro tests and benchmarks are rarely useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this no-op program:

```
package main

func main() {
}
```

and tracing the clone calls shows the same three `clone` calls:

```
$ go build nop.go
$ strace -e trace=clone ./nop
clone(child_stack=0xc000060000, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM) = 12602
clone(child_stack=0xc000062000, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM) = 12603
clone(child_stack=0xc00005c000, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM) = 12605
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

so what you have shown here is that Go is able to create a goroutine with *no* clone calls:

```
$ cat oneproc.go
package main

func dummy() {
}

func main() {
    go dummy()
}
$ go build oneproc.go
$ strace -e trace=clone ./oneproc
clone(child_stack=0xc000060000, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM) = 13090
clone(child_stack=0xc000062000, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM) = 13091
clone(child_stack=0xc00005c000, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM) = 13092
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

(which is not really surprising—Goroutines are not threads).

#### Go runtime (Go 1.11/12-ish)

You asked for additional details [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57724916/why-multiple-clone-system-calls-called-for-single-go-subroutine/57731926?noredirect=1#comment101912047_57731926) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57724916/why-multiple-clone-system-calls-called-for-single-go-subroutine/57731926?noredirect=1#comment101922113_57731926).  There is a [design document](https://golang.org/s/go11sched) for the current system (which no doubt will become out of date if it is not already), and of course, there is the [Go runtime source itself](https://golang.org/src/runtime/).

There is a pretty informative (and large) comment at the top of [proc.go](https://golang.org/src/runtime/proc.go) that talks about how goroutines ("G"s) are mapped into worker threads ("M"s) that have processor resources ("P").  This is only indirectly relevant to why there are initially three OS `clone` calls (resulting in 4 threads total), but it is all important.  Note that additional OS-level threads can and will be created later if and when it appears to be useful, especially if and when an M blocks in a system call.

The actual `clone` system calls happen through `newosproc` and `newosproc0` in [os_linux.go](https://golang.org/src/runtime/os_linux.go#L145).  Other, non-Linux OSes have their own separate implementations.  If you search for calls to `newosproc` you'll find just the one in `proc.go`, in function `newm1`.  This is called from two more places in `proc.go`: `newm` and `templateThread`.  The templateThread is a special helper that may never be used and (I believe) is not part of the three initial `clone`s, so we get to ignore it, and only look for calls to `newm`.  There are 6 of these, all in `proc.go`:

- `main` calls `systemstack(func() { newm(sysmon, nil) })`.  `sysmon` is also in `proc.go`; see it for what it does, which is partly to trigger garbage collection as needed, and partly to keep the rest of the scheduler going.
- `startTheWorldWithSema`, which lets the runtime system start up, calls `newm(nil, p)` for each P.  There is always at least one P, so this could be the second one.  However, there's an initial `m0` object, so this may not be a / the second one `clone`—it's not clear.
- In [`sigqueue.go`](https://golang.org/src/runtime/sigqueue.go), `signal_enable` calls `sigenable` (in [`signal_unix.go`](https://golang.org/src/runtime/signal_unix.go)) which, depending on values in `sigtable` (from [`sigtab_linux_generic.go`](https://golang.org/src/runtime/sigtab_linux_generic.go)) that are definitely true, winds up calling `ensureSigM` (also in `signal_unix.go`), which calls `LockOSThread`, which ensures that we'll create another M.  (The `go` in the closure within `ensureSigM` created the G to be bound to this new locked-to-OS-thread M.)  As these calls are fired up from `init` functions I think they happen before `startTheWorldWithSema` so that it creates the extra M in the loop noted above.  They might happen after starting the world, but in that case it's still a matter of getting the M created before entering your `main`.

All of this definitely accounts for *two* of the threads: one to run `sysmon` and one to handle signals.  It may or may not account for the third thread.  It's all based on *reading* the code, rather than actually running and testing it, so it may contain errors.

Comment: Do you have idea why these clone for simple main function of go program. Does these used for initialization of program.

Comment: The runtime wants several system threads, for purposes of the runtime itself. This is not specified anywhere and may change in the future. *Currently*, there's one thread for the garbage collector, one for handling signal delivery from the OS, and one that drops into your existing scheduler, with more created afterward when appropriate to schedule more goroutines on additional CPUs. (These details could vary from one OS to another, although currently they don't.)

Comment: please add this hypothesis into your answer. it is useful information.

Comment: It's not just a hypothesis: I inspected the source code. But it's specific implementation detail, subject to change at any time. For instance there's no particular reason the gc thread must be created immediately.

Comment: Thanks for inspecting. It is great information then defiantly it is very much useful information for other developers. Those who look inside how its happening. Please add to the answer. Also ***Why multiple clone system calls called for single go subroutine?* it was question also.